# Our outgoing emails are all being delayed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, delay

We are on Outlook 2010, and all of a sudden all our outgoing emails are being delayed. They are leaving the system, but not being delivered. Our internet is working fine.

This is the message I am getting:

> Delivery is delayed to these recipients or groups: "the name of the person I'm emailing" This message hasn't been delivered yet. Delivery will continue to be attempted. The server will keep trying to deliver this message for the next 1 days, 19 hours and 54 minutes. You'll be notified if the message can't be delivered by that time.

The reason I know they aren't being delivered is that we are working with clients who all didn't receive the emails. This is affecting all 12 of the active email addresses we have. No one's emails are getting through.

We can send emails to each other - though I can't send to myself.

I've tried a few times and I can't send emails to a yahoo. Though I can send emails from yahoo to the exchange.

Comment: Also include in your edited answer the steps you have already taken to discover your problem and what you have already found out during your investigation.

Comment: That is a good question +1, welcome to SuperUser. Can you please confirm if you can send emails internally OK, and can you send emails to your personal accounts OK (eg, send an email to GMAIL or Hotmail etc). Do you have access to the email logs (do you own/run your own SMTP servers or do you use an external service)?

Comment: Are you on Exchange, POP3? Also, did this issue always exist, or is it recent?

Comment: Please try to find the option in Outlook for displaying the headers for the mail which is reporting the delay.  If you post that info, we might be able to see where (on which server) the mails are hanging.  We should be able to see if they are leaving your Exchange Server or not.

Answer (score 2):

With the information available, my best guess would be that the emails are gray-listed, meaning that either your mail server configuration or your domain records contain errors which result in a temporary refusal of delivery. Another possibility would be of course that your domain was blacklisted by a third party service, which is consulted by the receiving side. Check your domain against http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to see if that is the case.

Usually the system is set to try again to delivery of the email after a certain amount of time, which usually results in a successful delivery - this would as well explain that the email is just delayed.

If you provide the email header of one of the sent emails, we will be able to tell you more.